# Android: Layout with translucent background and shadow around border only

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a rounded rectangle with a translucent background and a shadow around the edges (this was designed in Figma).

[image]

However, when trying to recreate the design in Android XML layout, using the elevation parameter, I get the following result.

[image]

The translucent background does have a shadow, but it also contains the shadow tint underneath the translucent part. How do I make it so the shadow is only applied to the edge of the rounded rectangle constraint layout so that the translucent part is still white and not tinted?

Here is the code for the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/container_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/container_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/container_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/container_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/cardview_backdrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        ...content

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the code for the cardview_backdrop.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent_white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```